# PHP strtotime returning wrong result when looking for a "first saturday" of a given month

Tags: php, strtotime

Very strange issue here, using PHP date I am suddenly getting the wrong timestamp back.

If you take a look on this [strtotime.co.uk example](https://strtotime.co.uk/?str=February+2020+First+Saturday), it should return the timestamp for 1st of February 2020, but it's instead returning the 8th of February which is the second Saturday.

This is an old application I built a while back and I've never noticed a problem before, it has worked with all months up until now. Any idea's what is causing it?

*Note that I found a post with an almost identical issue but it was different, as the user had not used the month and year in the passed string.*

Comment: It's in the details of [PHP's relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). Scroll down to find the note that says `Also observe that the "of" in "ordinal space dayname space 'of' " and "'last' space dayname space 'of' " does something special.`

Comment: This is it, thank you so much. It should be "first sat of February 2020"